# How to Fetch data in Local JSON with UISearchBar in a UITableview?

Tags: objective-c, json, uitableview, uisearchbar

I'm developing an application that has a Local Database of Dogs in .JSON

I'm able to Fetch all the data in a Tableview and it works perfectly as follow:

```
-(void)readDataFromFile
{
    NSString * filePath =[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"Dogs" ofType:@"json"];

    NSError * error;
    NSString* fileContents =[NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:filePath encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:&error];


    if(error)
    {
        NSLog(@"Error reading file: %@",error.localizedDescription);
    }


    rows = (NSArray *)[NSJSONSerialization
                                JSONObjectWithData:[fileContents dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]
                                options:0 error:NULL];
}
```

Now My Goal is to implement a **SEARCH System** via a Searchbar that allow me to find directly an Array in the JSON File. this is the configuration of the JSON:

```
[
    {
        "id": "6523",
        "ident": "00A",
        "type": "Pitbull",
        "name": "Rocky",

    },
    {
        "id": "6524",
        "ident": "00AK",
        "type": "Pitbull",
        "name": "Sam",

    },


 }
```

I would like when to write Rocky in the searchbar...it shows me all the information in the array.

**I Added this Search Method:**

```
#pragma Search Methods

- (void)filterContentForSearchText:(NSString*)searchText scope:(NSString*)scope
{
    NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF beginswith[c] %@", searchText];
    self.searchResults = [[self.array valueForKey:@"name"] filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate];



}

-(BOOL)searchDisplayController:(UISearchDisplayController *)controller shouldReloadTableForSearchString:(NSString *)searchString
{
    [self filterContentForSearchText:searchString
                               scope:[[self.searchDisplayController.searchBar scopeButtonTitles]
                                      objectAtIndex:[self.searchDisplayController.searchBar
                                                     selectedScopeButtonIndex]]];

    return YES;
}
```

**And this is my TableView Method**

```
#pragma mark - Table view data source

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    // Return the number of sections.
    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    if (tableView == self.searchDisplayController.searchResultsTableView) {
        return [self.searchResults count];

    } else {
        return 150;
    }


}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

    DogCell *cell = (DogCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"Cell"];

    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"cell";

    if(cell == nil)
    {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle
                                      reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    }

    if (tableView == self.searchDisplayController.searchResultsTableView) {


        cell.textLabel.text = [self.searchResults objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
```

//I WANNA GET ALSO The detail with Dog "ident";
//cell.detailTextLabel.text = [self.searchResults objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

```
    } else {

 cell.textLabel.text = [[self.array objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]valueForKey:@"name"];
        cell.detailTextLabel.text = [[self.array objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]valueForKey:@"ident"];


    }




    return cell;
}
```

Now I'm able to search thanks to the SearchBar, but i can't have the both values of JSON array. I mean :

1) When i search Rocky in the search bar i get a Cell contained only :

Rocky but not the ident

**My New Goal**

There is a Way to get both "ident & name" in the Cell after Search ?

Answer (score 1):

Include UISearchBarDelegate and implement its delegate methods.

Suppose you have

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSArray rows;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSArray resultRows;
```

and then you assign array with dogs.json so now rows contains all the data in json format.

```
- (void)searchBarSearchButtonClicked:(UISearchBar *)searchBar {

    NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"name CONTAINS[cd] %@",[searchBar text]];

    self.resultRows = [self.rows filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate];

    if (self.resultRows.count == 0) {

   //record not found and do stuff

    } else {
        //now self.resultRows contains the searched data
    }
    [searchBar resignFirstResponder]; 
}
```

And don't forget to set the delegate.

good luck

Comment: Can u tell me what problem you are facing ?

Comment: Just replace the line in code with

NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"name CONTAINS[cd] **%@**",[searchBar text]];

Comment: i put a new Edit, Please check it out

Comment: Try this : NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"name CONTAINS[cd] %@ OR ident CONTAINS[cd] %@",searchBar.text, searchBar.text];

Answer (score 1):

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSMutableArray nameArray;

@property (strong, nonatomic) NSMutableArray responseArray;
```

First store the name value in separate array.(if names are unique)

for(int i=0 ; i < responseArray.count;i++)
 {

```
  [nameArray addObject:[[responseArray objectAtIndex:i]objectForKey:@"name"]];
```

}

//name Array:(
    Rocky,
    Sam,
    Arun
)
//SearchBarText - @"Sam"

Then, find the index path of the name typed in search bar.

```
NSUInteger selectedIndex = [nameArray indexOfObject:searchBarText];
```

Using Selected index value , you can get that from response array where you took name by ObjectAtIndex.

Comment: i put a new Edit, Please check it out I don't how to move on